# Script aborts after adding a try block and writing to two log files

Tags: python, pxssh

I have a text file that is a list of servers which is called **solaris_h.txt**. Some of the servers on this list, I'm not able to authenticate probably because I don't have an account or the password is incorrect. When authentication fails on a particular server on the list, the script aborts. So, somebody suggested the `try` and `except` block. I want the script to complete the list of servers in **solaris_h.txt** and to write to a log file the successful logins and writing to another log file the servers that failed to authenticate.  After adding the `try` block, when executing the script, it exits immediately without error. And how do I get my script to write to one log file the successful logins and to another log file the unsuccessful logins?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import pxssh
import sys

log = open("myprog.log", "a")
sys.stdout = log

s = pxssh.pxssh(timeout=30, maxread=2000000)
s.SSH_OPTS += "-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no"
s.SSH_OPTS += "-o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null"
s.SSH_OPTS += "PubkeyAuthentication=no"

f=open('solaris_h.txt','r')
for line in f:

try:
    s.login(line,'xxxx','xxxxxx')
    z = s.sendline('uname -a')
    s.prompt()
    y = s.before
    print("%s %s" % (line, y))
    s.logout()
except pxssh.ExceptionPxssh:
    pass
```

Here is the error when it fails authentication.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./z.py", line 17, in <module>
 s.login(line,'username','password')
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pxssh.py", line 226, in login
  raise ExceptionPxssh ('password refused')
pxssh.ExceptionPxssh: password refused
```

Comment: @ Stephen Rauch  continue to the end of the text file.

Comment: Please indent what you've done correctly above - it's the only way we can help you diagnose the problem. Remember - indentation matters in python!

Comment: I indented, still, script exits.

Comment: Your script might be indented correctly - but your question isn't. We can't tell what you are doing unless you properly indent your question.

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: Good start. What about the for loop? Please spend a few moments proof reading your question - it saves people having to extract the information later.

Comment: I edited the question again.

Comment: I read the link, I edited the question and modified the body.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ignore an error from a failed login, you can do a `try/except` block around the login like:

```
try:
    s.login(line, 'username', 'password')
    z = s.sendline('uname -a')
    s.prompt()
    y = s.before
    print("%s %s" % (line, y))

    s.logout()
except pxssh.ExceptionPxssh:
    pass
```

Comment: I don't want to ignore the error, I want to write to a log file the successfuls and unsuccessfuls

Comment: And how did I know this when writing up the answer?

Comment: Now the script exits immediately without an error when I inserted the try/except.

Comment: That would depend on how you inserted the block.  If you inserted it correctly, then it will continue with the next line in `f`.

Comment: I need somebody to verify that I inserted the block correctly, my script exits immediately without error.

Comment: The script in your question is not correct.  I edited it earlier to make it so that it would at least compile, but you re-edited it, and put it back to how it is now.  So I assumed that is how you wanted it. And since as it is now it won't even compile, it is hard for me to say what will or won't work. My suggestion is to do what I do and use PyCharm.  A good debugger will make figuring these things out much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Use try except blocks for the authentication code alone. so if any errors they will be caught and loop will continue with next server name.